# Copying additional inputs to excel and filling automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy new data from a sheet every week to an already existing sheet having all the past data.  The Existing sheet columns(some) are also formulated using Vba. I have written the code which copies the data in to the sheet but the other columns are not filled up(or dragged) automatically.

```
Sub Transfernewdata()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows,     searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("D5:D" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4)
Range("C5:C" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
Range("B5:B" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)
Range("A5:A" & lastrow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Date
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I just transfer 4 columns and rest are to be filled up automatically. I try to put the date(last line of code) but even that doesn't fill up more than once. Any help is appreciated, also I don't understand that every module I run does not affect the new data added. 
[image]

Comment: When you say "rest are to be filled up automatically", are there additional rows (E-?) that have formulas that you're expecting to automatically populate into the newly filled rows?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes there are more columns. For Eg: I copy 100 rows with 4 columns , they get copied but the other columns whose value depend on these columns do not fill up. I'll need to drag to fill it but I want to do it through VBA. Also can you tell me if possible that why is the Date statement not filling up till the end. I think that should hint me on filling the other rows too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>change this:</strike>

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Date
```

to this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastrow & ":a65536") = Date
```

Based on the additional information you provided in the comments, below, I would suggest making your data into a table. The formulas should automatically copy themselves every time you insert a row into the table.

If you move your cursor to the top left corner of your data set then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> it will automatically tabelize all the contiguous data you already have there. (You'll have to tick or untick the 'My data has headers' question, as appropriate.)

Comment: This will lead the date going till 65536 rows, which is not required but Thanks for that.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're after. You'll have to try explaining it again. Maybe a picture or 'text graphics' to show your desired outcome.

Comment: I added images. So I always copy values of column B and Column c from another sheet. Now what I need is that when I add values of B and C then other columns should start filling up , because all they need is value of B and C, which I am copying but those columns don't fill in. Also the Date statement that you suggested fills date column till 65536 , whereas I only want it to fill it till the row having B and C inputs.